# Create variable numbers of string variables according to users's input(C language)

Tags: c, pointers

I would like to create an array of string variables, and the number of elements is depends on the user's input. For example, if the user's input is 3, then he can input 3 strings. Let's say "aaa", "bbb" and "ccc". They are stored by the same pointer to char(*ptr) but with different index.

code:

```
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    getchar();
    char *ptr = malloc(t*sizeof(char));
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        gets(*(ptr[i]));
    }
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        puts(*(ptr[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

t is the number of elements, *ptr is the pointer to array. I would like to store "aaa", "bbb" and "ccc" in ptr[0], ptr[1] and ptr[2]. However, errors have been found in gets and puts statement and i am not able to work out a solution. Would someone give a help to me? Thank you!

Comment: please also share what is the description of the error.

Comment: "They are stored by the same pointer to char(*ptr) but with different index." What do you mean by this?

Comment: you are working with strings but allocating/incrementing for single chars.

Comment: @ImranAli the error is test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:15:8: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
test.c:19:8: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)

for the statements of gets and puts

Comment: @MikeCAT I am sorry that my English is not good, so maybe not explaining it well. I meant i want those strings stored by the same arrayName(which is ptr), by using different index(0,1,2,3, ......) to access them

Comment: @lossleader I still dont have idea how to solve this problem in am easy way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, deprecated in C99 and deleted from C11.
- Only one character can be stored in `char`. If the maximum length of strings to be inputted is fixed, you can allocate an array whose elements are arrays of `char`. Otherwise, you should use an array of `char*`.

Try this (this is for former case):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* the maximum length of strings to be read */
#define STRING_MAX 8

int main(void)
{
    int t;
    if (scanf("%d", &t) != 1)
    {
        fputs("read t error\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    getchar();
    /* +2 for newline and terminating null-character */
    char (*ptr)[STRING_MAX + 2] = malloc(t*sizeof(char[STRING_MAX + 2]));
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        return 1;
    }
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        if (fgets(ptr[i], sizeof(ptr[i]), stdin) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "read ptr[%d] error\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
        /* remove newline character */
        char *lf;
        if ((lf = strchr(ptr[i], '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0';
    }
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        puts(ptr[i]);
    }

    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks MikeCAT! I find that your code can solve the problem. However, there are some parts i dont understand since my knowledge about C isnt good enough.

Comment: first part:
#define STRING_MAX 8

you defined that the max length of the string to be read is 8. However, when i input 2 for t, aaaaaaaa(8) and aaaaaaaaa(9) for the 2 strings, i find that the output would be aaaaaaaa(8) and aaaaaaaaa(9). The second string has exceeded the max length of 8, but can still be outputted properly.

Comment: 2nd part:
  char (*ptr)[STRING_MAX + 2] = malloc(t*sizeof(char[STRING_MAX + 2]));

why do we need to include [String_MAX+2] inside sizeof(char) instead of just sizeof(char)?

Comment: 3rd part:

    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        return 1;
    }

i would like to know when will this signal of error occur? When i am asked to input strings, i dont type anything just pressing enter, the output will still be enter instead of "malloc".

Comment: 4th part:

        char *lf;
        if ((lf = strchr(ptr[i], '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0';

i dont understand what these 2 lines uses for.

Comment: @GarethLam 1. When 9-character word is inputted, the newline character after that will remain in the input stream. You'll find it isn't working when you try entering next word after 9-character word. 2. To get the size of arrays to be allocated as elements. 3. When memory allocation fails, which will seldom happens. 4. Its role is in the comment. Search for newline character via `strchr()` and overwrite it by null-character if found.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mike !

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code which is given below because string array is like char 2D array so use can use pointer of pointer and when you allocate memory at run time by malloc then you need to cast into pointer to pointer char type.

```
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    char **ptr = (char **)malloc(t*sizeof(char));
    int i,j;

    for( i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",ptr[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        puts(ptr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mohit Prakash, thanks for your reply. But i find that your solution has some problems.
After i input 2 for t, i input "aaa" for the first string. Then, an error of "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" has been told which makes the program determined.

Comment: This code invokes *undefined behavior* by using values in buffer allocated via `malloc()` and not initiaized, which is indeterminate. Another *undefined behavior* may be invoked via out-of-range access if `sizeof(char*) > sizeof(char)`, which is typical.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, of a clean if slightly memory inefficient way to handle this. A more memory efficient solution would use one string of MAX_LINE_LENGTH and copy to strings of precise lengths.. which is why one contiguous block of memory for the strings is a bad idea.

The asserts also just demonstrate where real checks are needed as malloc is allowed to fail in production where asserts do nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 2048

int
main(void) {

    int tot, i;
    char **strheads; /* A pointer to the start of the char pointers */


    if (scanf("%d\n", &tot) < 1)
        return (1); 

    strheads = malloc(tot * sizeof (char *));
    assert(strheads != NULL);
    /* now we have our series of n pointers to chars,
       but nowhere allocated to put the char strings themselves. */

    for (i = 0; i < tot; i++) {
        strheads[i] = malloc(sizeof (char *) * MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
        assert(strheads[i] != NULL);
        /* now we have a place to put the i'th string,
           pointed to by pointer strheads[i] */
        (void) fgets(strheads[i], MAX_LINE_LENGTH, stdin);
    }
    (void) printf("back at ya:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < tot; i++) {
        fputs(strheads[i], stdout);
        free(strheads[i]); /* goodbye, i'th string */
    }

    free(strheads); /* goodbye, char pointers [0...tot] */

    return (0);
}
```